# WPF override OnClosing still clears DataContext even if e.Cancel = true

Tags: wpf

***Never mind... found it... and see why too...***

I've looked around on WPF, and overriding the OnClosing of a WPF window to prevent closing window under whatever conditions... Such as editing and getting user confirmation before allowing the window to close.  Done that many times before, but under C# WinForms.

In WPF, I have my VMMV and the ViewModel is set as the "DataContext" to the WPF Window, no problem... all fields bound, refreshed, enable/disable as needed, etc.  As soon as I click the close button, the "OnClosing" that has been overridden goes to my function and asks a confirmation to close or not... nothing special.  If ok, allow to continue.  if NOT, I set e.Cancel = true (to abort the closing of the window).

```
public void ViewModelClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (MessageBox.Show("Close the current window?", "Close", 
         MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
      // Nope, do not allow the window to close, so "CANCEL" the close window operation
      e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However, as SOON as I send my OnClosing function is finished, the "DataContext" of the Window is gone, and so too are all the respective "Bindings".  Am I missing something simple?

--- EDIT --- 
Oops, clarification.  I am not using any specific framework, but my own of a class with properties and ICommands.  The function above is called from the Window's  OnClosing hook into the event list doesn't work...

```
OnClosing += myViewModel.ViewModelClosing;
```

But strangely, if I just leave the window's overridden directly (it does NOT break the bindings)

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if( MessageBox.Show( "Ok to close", "Closing", MessageBoxButton.YesNo ) 
        == MessageBoxResult.No )
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any MVVM framework? How are you handling your VM when its view gets closed?

Comment: It might serve you well to answer your own question, rather than editing your OP.

Comment: @TankorSmash, really... commenting for a post 2+ years ago on something that was already solved / answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with hyp. Nothing in WPF itself automatically clears the DataContext. You are likely using some MVVM Framework that does that for you to prevent memory leaks, but obviously is doing it too eagerly.

Comment: Found it slightly after your answer to look into debug stepping into it...